# Regex with optional quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following `<INPUTBOX:(")?(?s:.\n)?(.*?)(?(1)")(:)?(?(3)((")?.*?(?(5)")))>`

It's almost doing what I need - extract string1 and (if its present) string2.

I have a string with one or more of `<INPUTBOX:string1:string2>`
Both string1 and string2 may have optional quotes - "string1"

string2 is optional and the ':' is only valid if followed by string2.

string1 may start with a newline (\n) after the first quote (") in which case the newline should not be part for the returned value.

Currently string1 = group2 and string2 = group4

[example regex](https://regex101.com/r/OUvFHF/5)

Is there a cleaner or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Try `<INPUTBOX:(?:"(?<x>[^"]*)"(?::"(?<y>[^"]*)")?|(?<x>[^>]*))`

Comment: @ctwheels - This is much faster thanks - however your solution doesn't recognizer string2 unless it has quotes (and the last <x> generates an error, so I changed it to <z>)

Comment: @johnny5 - it does support optional quotes - I just think there might be a more efficient way to do it - anything wrong with asking for help with this?

Comment: Maybe something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/OUvFHF/6) would be sufficient.

Comment: @bobblebubble - very close thanks, the last inputbox  should fail to match because of the trailing ':'

Comment: @MichaelTissington [See update](https://regex101.com/r/OUvFHF/7) what you mean? Actaully that's what I thought before, but was unclear.

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: @bobblebubble - great thanks - happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - would you care to elaborate or give me an example please?

Comment: Reread your question (as it is displayed) and you will see.

Comment: @MichaelTissington To me still unclear what you mean with *string1 may start with a "\n" in which case it should be ignored.* Hope my comment regex helped, imho Casimir is right. Please try to clarify question / expected result :)

Comment: @bobblebubble - hopefully it's clearer now?